# EOS Block Producer Schedule

Tags: cleos, nodeos, eosio-code, eosiocpp, eosio.system

I have followed the Boot Bios sequence of eosio and setup a eos private blockchain. The problem is my even though i have created also Block producers and also voted for them still the blocks are getting signed or produced by only eosio not my created block producers and also in the schedule list of block producers there's only eosiowith its producer key. Can anyone help me out with this that how to put the created block producers on the block producers schedule list.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to register 21 BPs.

Second, Check the token.
In order to change the BP, requirement is minimum 15% of tokens have been staked to producers votes.

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence //chapter 3.

If you issued the token 10000 EOS, 1500 of tokens have been staked to producers votes.

And, if you want to edit the BP's number

https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/c046863a65d7e98424312ee8009f0acb493e6231/contracts/eosio.system/src/voting.cpp#L88

```
 void system_contract::update_elected_producers( block_timestamp block_time ) {
  _gstate.last_producer_schedule_update = block_time;

  auto idx = _producers.get_index<"prototalvote"_n>();

  std::vector< std::pair<eosio::producer_key,uint16_t> > top_producers;
  top_producers.reserve(21); 

  for ( auto it = idx.cbegin(); it != idx.cend() && top_producers.size() < 21 && 0 < it->total_votes && it->active(); ++it ) {
     top_producers.emplace_back( std::pair<eosio::producer_key,uint16_t>({{it->owner, it->producer_key}, it->location}) );
  }.  

  if ( top_producers.size() < _gstate.last_producer_schedule_size ) {
     return;
  }
```

21 --> Desired number

Fianlly. Check the vote producer

```
./cleos system listproducers
```

you can see how many staked token were voted

Comment: The requirement of 15% tokens needing to be staked is incorrect.

There is a `min_activated_stake` variable that is hardcoded to 150M, https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/master/contracts/eosio.system/include/eosio.system/eosio.system.hpp#L67

I have already opened an issue regarding this incorrect error message. It should either tell the user to stake 150M+ tokens, or the contract logic needs to be altered to check the max_supply of the tokens issued to determine the min_activated_stake.

https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/issues/291

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to issue and stake over 150M tokens from the `eosio.token` contract as it is hardcoded into the `eosio.system` contract, https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/master/contracts/eosio.system/include/eosio.system/eosio.system.hpp#L67.

*There is no additional requirement to register 21+ BPs.*

#### Complete Steps to Activate Fully Featured Testnet

- Add `producer1` to nodeos config.ini along with private signing key
- Create system blockchain accounts

  - `eosio.token`
  - `eosio.msig`
  - `eosio.bpay`
  - `eosio.names`
  - `eosio.ram`
  - `eosio.ramfee`
  - `eosio.saving`
  - `eosio.stake`
  - `eosio.vpay`
  - `eosio.rex`
- Deploy system contracts (bios before system)

  - `eosio.bios`
  - `eosio.token`
  - `eosio.msig`
  - `eosio.system`
- Create EOS token with **at LEAST 150M supply**
- Issue tokens to eosio and stake **at LEAST 150M tokens**
- Create `producer1` account
- Register `producer1` as BP with private signing key setup in config.ini
- Vote `producer1` as BP
- Testnet is now active and should be fully functional with `producer1` signing blocks

---

I have already [filed an issue](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/issues/291) with the `eosio.system` contract to resolve the erroneous error message or logic.